# UNziping zip files

Tags: php, laravel, archive

Laravel 5.31.3 PHP I want to search through a list of zip files for a string. How do I make sure I don't use all the space.

I want the users to be able to search through archive files without necessarily knowing the exact date the transaction they are searching took place, so I would need to loop through a directory, unzipping files in memory only, to look for the result.
I am worried unzipping all these archives would cause space issues in my  system.  I'd like to know how I could free the space when I'm done, and/or monitor space consumption to prevent issues

Comment: If you extracted everything, how much extra space are we talking about? 10MB, 100MB, 1GB, 1100GB? And how often are users going to do this? Once a month, every 5 seconds? " I am worried unzipping all these archives would cause space issues in my system" - you should be able to calculate.

Comment: "I'd like to know how to...monitor space consumption to prevent issues" - That's something that is probably host-specific, and you probably wouldn't tackle directly in PHP (unless you built something to do so).

Comment: Not sure about the space - will get back to you on that.  As for how often, this would be occasionally, when someone needs to access past records.

Comment: You need _n_ bytes of space and that costs _m_ (from your hosting provider, IT, whatever). Is this feature used enough to be worth _m_? Maybe only special users get this. If this is a paid site, maybe it is an add-on. Or, maybe _n_ is small enough that _m_ doesn't really matter and you are just willing to eat it.

Comment: I have been looking into this, and the average zipped file is less than 1800kb, with some exceptions.

Comment: I have also been checking into how much space it will take to unzip,  each file should take in the neighbourhood of  7035378 bytes (there is one very large file which would take 389947085, but that's very much an exception)  I think my next steps should be to find out 1) if there is space available. 2) if I unzip more than 1 file at a time, can 1 reclaim the space? 3) Can I stop the users from unzipping a file which is too large?

Comment: Any advice on how to go about any of this would be greatly appreciated.